# What query would get the latest rows for a specifics user for different categories?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Title is kind of confusing. But I have a table that keeps entries for users from different categories. So there are categories `A`, `B`, and `C` and a user may have many entries in each. I need an SQL query that will get the latest 1 entry (sorted by `created_at`) for each category, hopefully in one query. This is Rails, so it can be an actual SQL query or ActiveRecord.

Columns used would be `user_id`, `category` (which will have only `A`, `B`, or `C`), `created_at`, and `notes` (this is where is the actual information I need).

Comment: Please update your question with your models information i.e. the model names with their column names and their associations, so that we can give you more accurate answer for your question.

Comment: For a single user_id, or all user_ids?

Comment: Why are you wishing to use  a SQL query instead of Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming all the columns mentioned are present in your `users` table):

```
  User.group("users.category").
      select("users.id as user_id", "users.category", "MAX(users.created_at) as created_at", "users.notes")
```

Answer (score 0):

We assume a single user here (you title says `for a specific user`).

Basically we are querying for this:

```
SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries"
LEFT JOIN entries e2 ON (
  entries.category=e2.category AND
  entries.created_at < e2.created_at AND
  entries.user_id = e2.user_id)
WHERE e2.id IS NULL AND entries.user_id=?
```

Translated into Rails:

```
user_id = @user.id
data = Entry.joins(%q{LEFT JOIN entries e2 ON (
  entries.category = e2.category AND
  entries.created_at < e2.created_at AND
  entries.user_id = e2.user_id
)}).where("e2.id IS NULL AND entries.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

If you need last notes by categories you get them from `res`:

```
by_category = data.map{|e| [e.category, e.notes]}.to_h
```

**Note** Your requirement was to compare entries by `created_at` date. I would suggest to use `id` instead. So you might write it like this:

```
user_id = @user.id
data = Entry.joins(%q{LEFT JOIN entries e2 ON (
  entries.category = e2.category AND
  entries.id < e2.id AND
  entries.user_id = e2.user_id
)}).where("e2.id IS NULL AND entries.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three simple SQL methods for this, and there are more but I'm not sure of the extent to which MySQL supports window functions and whatnot.

1 Find entries for which the created_at is the maximum for that user_id and category. Problematic if two entries have the same created_at as two rows will be returned for one user and category.

```
select *
from   entries
where  created_at = (
         select max(e.created_at)
         from   entries e
         where  e.user_id = entries.user_id and
                e.category = entries.category)
```

2 Find entries for which the id the the first one for that user and category when the rows are order by created_at desc. Problematic if two entries have the same created_at as the one row returned is non-deterministic, but you can order by id as well to make it so.

```
select *
from   entries
where  id = (
         select e.id
         from   entries e
         where  e.user_id = entries.user_id   and
                e.category = entries.category
         order by created_at desc
         limit    1)
```

3 Find entries for which there exists no other having a greater created_at for that user and category. Problematic if two entries have the same created_at as two rows will be returned for one user and category.

```
 select *
 from   entries
 where  not exists (
          select e.id
          from   entries e
          where  e.user_id  = entries.user_id   and
                 e.category = entries.category  and
                 e.created_at > entries.created_at)
```

All of these should be pretty efficient, but none are very amenable to expression in ActiveRecord. Any of them could have the where clause represented as a scope, just to encapsulate it nicely in the model, and then it can be merged into an association:

```
has_many :latest_category_entries, -> {merge(:latest_category)}, class_name => "Entry"
```

... so you can:

```
@user.latest_category_entries
```

and:

```
User.includes(:latest_category_entries).each do |user|
  user.latest_category_entries.each do |entry|
    etc ...
```